# Trying to implement a simple responsive progress bar with issues

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

I've followed the instructions from the site I obtained the information off and now I'm stuck. The code is as follows:

HTML

```
<div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="25">
    <div class="progress-bar progress"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS Code

```
 .progress {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

.progress-wrap {
    background: #f80;
    margin: 20px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.progress-bar {
    background: #ddd;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

And JS

```
// on page load...
moveProgressBar();
// on browser resize...
$(window).resize(function() {
    moveProgressBar();
});

// SIGNATURE PROGRESS
function moveProgressBar() {
    console.log("moveProgressBar");
    var getPercent = ($('.progress-wrap').data('progress-percent') / 100);
    var getProgressWrapWidth = $('.progress-wrap').width();
    var progressTotal = getPercent * getProgressWrapWidth;
    var animationLength = 2500;

    // on page load, animate percentage bar to data percentage length
    // .stop() used to prevent animation queueing
    $('.progress-bar').stop().animate({
        left: progressTotal
    }, animationLength);
}
```

With the JavaScript file when I load in chrome I get an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'data' of null

I don't know what to do next. I've extensively searched Google but my knowledge of JavaScript is slowly eluding me.

Comment: It would appear as though your code is running before the DOM has been loaded. Is the // on page load... comment at the top meant to indicate that the all of that code runs inside of a call to $(document).ready()? If not, I think that may be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs without errors. I just changed HTML part from this:

```
<div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="25">
```

to this

```
<div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="25">
    <div class="progress progress-bar"/>
</div>
```

so that animation is visible.

There you have working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fHqKR/2/).

Based on the error message you provided I would say that you have problem somewhere else.

Comment: My first question on this site and i input everything wrong lol the code sample didnt include that bit all though it was there when i edited it. all of that part is present is there any steps i can take to diagnose it?

Comment: Please take a look at this: [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) sections [Working With The console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) and [Debugging JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging). Try to find out where error occours and ask new question (don't forget to provide the code snippet where error occours).